# Simple cron job for generating random wallpaper with nitrogen

Tags: cron

I am trying to create a **cron job** that will **change my desktop wallpaper every minute**. I created a new job using crontab -e.

***/1 * * * * /usr/bin/nitrogen --set-zoom-fill --random /home/rkr/Pictures/wallpapers-master/**

The command works on the shell very well. The cron job is also running and visible in **/var/log/syslog**. 
I tried to debug it by sending the output to a log file, which reports a warning about nitrogen :

(nitrogen:10468): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:37:01.654: cannot open display:

I don't think that is the issue though. To further verify if my cron is working I tried :

***/1 * * * * touch /home/rkr/Videos/file** and the file was created.

Now I am confused if this is the issue with nitrogen.

Answer (score 1):

#### Hello

It depends...
I think the issue is the environment.
Having a Terminal open in X and type:

```
env | grep DISPLAY
```

This gives the information you need to set the Display for nitrogen.
Because the cronjob sh/bash dont have this variable set.
Now your best friend is env too for starting nitrogen in crontab.

```
env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 nitrogen
```

...much fun.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the crontab to this : */1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/riteshkr/wall-change.sh and it worked.